# Why is it legal to initialize an object with brace init even though it is not an aggregate?

Tags: c++, c++11

I don't understand why Variant 1 is allowed.

```
class A {
public:
    A(int x, int y) : a{x}, b{y} {}

private:
    int a;
    int b;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    // Variant 1
    //B(int x, int y, int z) : A{x,y}, c{z} {}

    // Variant 2
    B(int x, int y, int z) : A(x,y), c{z} {}
private:
    int c;
};

int main() {
    B b(1,2,3);
}
```

This code is build with -std=c++11.

1. Which of variant 1 and 2 is better, and why?
2. Here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization it says that for brace init to be allowed, the class must be an aggregate, which A is not. Why does this still compile?

Comment: The linked page does not say that for brace init to be allowed, the class must be an aggregate .

Comment: It's not aggregate initialization, it's just brace initialization, which simply calls an appropriate constructor.

Comment: It's called *brace initialization* or *uniform initialization*.

Comment: @MariusBancila: It's called _list initialisation_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization it says that for brace init to be allowed, the class must be an aggregate, which A is not. Why does this still compile?

It also says:

> Aggregate initialization is a form of [list-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), which initializes aggregates

This is not aggregate initialization as you correctly surmised. It's still allowed, though, as list-initialization. Sinces C++11 braces can be used to initialize things that are not aggregates. It simply does not count as aggregate initialization.

Comment: Is it (2) in the list in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization that takes place? 

Is it correct to assume that this part is where the constructor is chosen? "If the previous stage does not produce a match, all constructors of T participate in overload resolution against the set of arguments that consists of the elements of the braced-init-list, with the restriction that only non-narrowing conversions are allowed."

Answer (score 6):

> http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization it says that for brace init to be allowed, the class must be an aggregate

No, it says that for aggregate initialisation to be performed, the class must be an aggregate.

But your code does not perform aggregate initialisation; it performs [list initialisation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).

Answer (score 0):

I believe one of the goals of C++11 was to have a uniform initialization syntax so that rather than having to think about whether to use `=`, `( )` or `= { }` to perform initialization you could simply use `{ }` everywhere.